# Can I override which scripts are loaded by Juice UI?

Tags: juice-ui

This is a follow on question to SO Question - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9741880/136717).

Is it possible to override which scripts are loaded w/o recompiling juice?  Or to add a script for a custom jquery-ui based control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a jQuery UI widget that you want to hook up to Juice UI, you can do so very easily. There isn't any documentation for the process as yet, but there are lots of examples you can follow. I'd recommend taking a look at the ProgressBar.cs file and how it matches to the ui-progressbar.js file in the jQuery UI source. You can also have a look at the source code for Wijmo Open for Juice UI - they built an entire extension library using Juice UI to hook up their jQuery UI widget library.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer -
For JavaScript files, I just have to re-define the script definitions that are in the JuiceApp.cs file to point to where I need them to.  I'm doing this in Global.asx - Application_Start method.